# Условный императив

Tags: наклонение

Помогите, пожалуйста, разобраться в следующих двух пунктах:

Здесь (http://rusgram.ru/%D0%98%D0%BC%D0%BF%D0%B5%D1%80%D0%B0%D1%82%D0%B8%D0%B2#48) читаю:

> Условный императив, [...], обладает целым рядом свойств, которые
>   говорят о его существенной грамматикализации:
>
> 1) допускает подлежащее всех трех лиц;
>
> 2) не присоединяет показателя множественного числа;
>
> ......

Вопрос к №1

Сделала пример *"Знай я об этом, я бы пришел раньше"* и обратилась к носителю русского языка на факультете. Он говорит, "в 1., 2. и 3. лице множественного лица звучит странно" - *"Знай мы/вы/они об этом, мы/вы/они бы пришли раньше".* Скажите, пожалуйста, это предложение в формах множественных лиц на самом деле звучит странно или оно странно для него, потому что он долгое время не живет в стране?

Вопрос к №2

> 2) не присоединяет показателя множественного числа;

Что имеется в виду здесь? Совсем не поняла это =(

Большое спасибо!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

1) Повелительное наклонение (императив) в русском языке имеет **две стандартные грамматические формы,** которые соответствуют **2-му лицу ед. и мн. числа**: *возьми — возьмиТЕ, знай — знайТЕ, брось — бросьТЕ.*

Когда императив употребляется в значении сослагательного (условного) наклонения, он **изменяет свои грамматические возможности** (подвергается существенной грамматикализации):

(а) он может относиться **не только ко 2-му лицу, но и ко всем трем лицам;**

(б) он уже **не имеет формы мн. числа,** то есть **окончания ТЕ** (которое является **показателем мн. числа**).

2) **Примеры из художественной литературы:**

**Знай мы** это, сразу бы вышли на убийцу. [Евгений Сухов. Делу конец -- сроку начало (2007)]

**Знай я** об этом хоть за сутки, не уверен, как поступил бы. [Армен Медведев. Территория кино (1999-2001)]

Неужели ты действительно считаешь, что, **знай ты** эту тайну, ты решила бы все проблемы? [Виктор Пелевин. Девятый сон Веры Павловны (1991)]

Что сказал бы майор, **знай он** о существовании чемодана?.. [Михаил Гиголашвили. Чертово колесо (2007)]

**Знай они** о походе казаков к «тунгусам», не преминули бы его прокомментировать. [Д. И. Саврасов. Дело о редкостях, или первопроходцы (2003-2008)]

3) И ваш пример **в трех лицах:**

**Знай я** об этом, пришел бы раньше.

**Знай они** об этом, пришли бы раньше.

**Знай ты** об этом, то, наверное, пришел бы раньше.

Comment: спасибо за ответ! извините, я переспрошу, правильно понимаю или нет: императив как замена сосл.н. никогда не имеет формы во мн.ч., но может иметь как субъект все лица (единст. И МНОЖ.), правильно? то есть предложение "Знай мы/вы/они об этом, мы/вы/они бы пришли раньше" не звучит странно?

Comment: Да, всё правильно, я поэтому и привела примеры их худ. литературы. Из них видно, что инфинитив сочетается с тремя лицами, но при этом имеет только форму ед. числа (нет окончания мн. числа  ТЕ).

Comment: большое спасибо! восхищаюсь какая вы умная! приезжаите к нам в Испанию учить нас! наш русскии доцент плохо объясняет и знает только как кричать =)

Answer (score 2):

> Вопрос к №1
>
> Сделала пример "Знай я об этом, я бы пришел раньше" и обратилась к
>   носителю русского языка на факультете. Он говорит, "в 1., 2. и 3. лице
>   множественного лица звучит странно" - "Знай мы/вы/они об этом,
>   мы/вы/они бы пришли раньше". Скажите, пожалуйста, это предложение в
>   формах множественных лиц на самом деле звучит странно или оно странно
>   для него, потому что он долгое время не живет в стране?

Если вы попытались использовать "знай" во множественном числе, то это действительно странно. Но только в этом случае. ***Знай мы/вы/они об этом, мы/вы/они бы пришли раньше".*** - абсолютно корректная конструкция для всех лиц.

> Вопрос к №2
>
> ```
> 2) не присоединяет показателя множественного числа;
> ```
>
> Что имеется в виду здесь? Совсем не поняла это =(

А это скорее всего как раз о том, на чем споткнулся ваш носитель. *Знай мы* - не "знайте мы". В этой форме глагол "знай" ("знать") внешне напоминает обычный императив, но не имеет формы множественного числа. 
Исторически это вообще не императив, поэтому правильнее сказать, что это именно условная форма, омонимичная императиву. Название "условный императив" отражает именно это сходство, грамматики императива тут нету. А коли так, то вопрос о присоединении показателя множественного числа (-те) просто лишен смысла.

Comment: большое спасибо! по всеи видимости неправильно сформулировала вопрос. хотела знать: "это предложение с местоимениями/подлежащими в формах множественных лиц на самом деле звучит странно?" тот мальчик сказал, звучит странно как "Знай мы/вы/они об этом, мы/вы/они бы пришли раньше" и носитель языка предпочел бы конструкцию с "если бы": "если бы мы/вы/они знали об этом, мы/вы/они пришли бы раньше". поэтому я пришла думать может есть какая-то стилистическая разница...

Comment: *и носитель языка предпочел бы конструкцию с "если бы"* - он неправ. Эти две конструкции тождественны по смыслу, и по стилистике. Более, того, я бы предпочел именно ваш вариант, поскольку    вариант с "если бы" и длиннее, и требует двух "бы" (если **бы** мы знали, то сделали **бы**), что немного режет слух, хотя в данном случае и не запрещено.

Comment: спасибо за помощь! очень ценю!